I am encountering an error while setting up CocoaPods for my Flutter iOS project. The error occurs in my Podfile. Here are the details:
Invalid Podfile file: undefined method `exists?' for class File.
def flutter_root
generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.expand_path(File.join('..', 'Flutter', 'Generated.xcconfig'), FILE)
unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
raise "#{generated_xcode_build_settings_path} must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
end
I have ensured that Generated.xcconfig exists and have run flutter pub get. Despite this, the error persists.
How can I fix this issue and successfully run pod install?
Additional Information:
Flutter version: 3.7.12
Xcode version: Version 14.3
macOS version: Version 13.4
Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
